# Express middleware to configure response

Tags: node.js, express, middleware

I want to create a middleware that automatically formats my output and returns it in a format that looks like

```
{
   "successful": "true",
   "message": "Successfully created",
   "data": {
         "name": "Joe",
         "year": 1
    }
}
```

Currently I'm just returning a json of the data itself (name, year, etc.)

I want to add the "successful", "message", etc.

Here's some snippets of my code below:

**routes/student.js**

```
var student_controller = require('../controllers/studentController');
router.get('/list', student_controller.student_list);
```

**controllers/student.js**

```
var Student = require('../models/student');

exports.student_list = function(req, res, next) {
    Student.find()
        .exec(function(err, list_students) {
            if (err) {return next(err);}
            res.json(list_students);
        });
};
```

**app.js**

```
var studentRouter = require('./routes/student');
app.use('/student', studentRouter);
```

How do I make this middleware, and in which file(s) should I be calling it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The response can be intercepted by overriding `response.json` function. By doing so, and adding our `custom function`, every time, `response.json()` is called, our intercepting function is triggered.

middleware/response.filter.js:

```
// Response Interceptor Middleware
export default (request, response, next) => {
    try {
        const oldJSON = response.json;
        response.json = (data) => {
            // For Async call, handle the promise and then set the data to `oldJson`
            if (data && data.then != undefined) {
                // Resetting json to original to avoid cyclic call.
                return data.then((responseData) => {
                    // Custom logic/code. -----> Write your logic to add success wrapper around the response
                    response.json = oldJSON;
                    return oldJSON.call(response, responseData);
                }).catch((error) => {
                    next(error);
                });
            } else {
                // For non-async interceptor functions
                // Resetting json to original to avoid cyclic call.
                // Custom logic/code.
                response.json = oldJSON;
                return oldJSON.call(response, finalResponse);
            }
        }
    } catch (error) {
        next(error);
    }
}
```

In the `Server.js` file, register the middleware:

```
// Server.js file
import externalResponseFilter from "./middleware/response.filter.js:";

// Create Express server
const app = express();

// Response interceptor - Initialization.
app.use(externalResponseFilter);
```

And in the controller where you are returning the `response`, return with `response.json()` function instead of `response.send()`.

Let me know if any additional explanation is required.

Comment: Thanks for your solution. It's not working for some reason. I copy-pasted it and when I run it and send a requests, the API just stops working.

Comment: Did you try debugging it? Meaning add a debugger and see where in the API the control is stopping

Comment: I did but it's not returning any error. Not sure if you know what I mean but the request sort of just keeps "running" as if it's waiting for something but it never returns anything and eventually just crashes.

Comment: Yeah. I understand what you are saying. My point being, why wait for response. Use the **debugger** and **add breakpoints** along the flow of execution. And then see, where the control is lost. This way, you don't have to wait for response.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no need to middleware in your case unless you need an auth check for this routing. The Middleware has the functionality to handle something before getting your response.
your code shall be:

```
    router.get('/list',(req,res,next)=>{
    Student.find().then(data=>res.json(data)).catch(err=>conole.log(err)) });
```

Comment: I want to add the "successful", "message", "data" return format for all my functions. I don't want to do this manually every time I return something, as it's not scalable.

Comment: a successful message to be rended in the Frontend ?

Comment: in the backend. What I mean is when I call "get", I don't want to return just the data. I want to return a json with other elements, then return the data in one of the elements of the json.

Comment: add a console.log(' your message');